# The probability of the element at index $i$ is greater than all following items

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider an array which is a permutation of $[1,2,3,\dotsc,n]$.
Each of the permutation is equally likely (Uniform distribution).

What is the probability that the item at index $i$ is greater than all the elements in $[i+1,\dotsc,n-1]$? (array index start from $0$)

I was thinking like:

There are $n!$ choices in the sample space.
And for item at index $i$ greater than the following, it has to be at least $n-i$ or greater.
And then I am struggling finding the answer.

Comment: Hint: You can pick the first i elements freely. Then the item at index i must be the biggest one you have left. Then you pick the rest freely.

Comment: There are $n-i$ positions with indices from $i$ to $n-1$. The biggest one among these is equally likely to be in any one of these positions. Thus the probability the item at position $i$ is bigger than the subsequent ones is  $\frac{1}{n-i}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now i know how to solve it!